# How Get Length of response in ASP.net Web API controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In a WEBAPI filter, im trying to calculate response size.
A similar process works for MVC controllers.

Inside   actionExecutedContext.Response.  i cant see a filter?

So I tried this filter below but this doesnt work.

How can i get the length of a WEBApi response ?
I could stick this in Global.ASAX and it works, but then every http call is logged...
So an API filter would be ideal. Is there something obviously wrong here ?

```
public class BosAPIFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        var httpContext = actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
        if (httpContext != null) {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.
            httpContext.Response.Filter = new ResponseStreamHandler(httpContext.Response.Filter);
            var handler = httpContext.Response.Filter as ResponseStreamHandler;
            var adminService = new AdminServices();
            adminService.HttpTrace(httpContext, handler);
        }
    }


 public class ResponseStreamHandler : MemoryStream {
    private readonly Stream _responseStream;
    public long ResponseSize { get; private set; }

    public ResponseStreamHandler(Stream responseStream) {
        this._responseStream = responseStream;
        ResponseSize = 0;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
        this.ResponseSize += count;
        this._responseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }


    // ReSharper disable once RedundantOverridenMember
    public override void Flush() { base.Flush(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Web API pipeline, action filters run before the result you return from the action method gets serialized. If you look at `actionExecutedContext.Response.Content` inside the filter, it will be `System.Net.Http.ObjectContent` (depending on your action method). So, you can calculate the response size only later in the pipeline. You can use a message handler to do this but then the granularity is not at the action method level. The lowest granularity you can get is at a route level. One way you get around this is to set a flag in the request dictionary from the filter and log from the handler only when the flag is set.